# scope.$watch not firing on variable change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

I have the following snippet of code below. The problem I'm having is that whenever the value of modal.isOpen is set to true, the $watch statement does not fire. I'm trying to avoid using scope.$apply. What am I doing wrong here...

Inside Link function in an Angular directive:

```
              link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

              scope.$watch('modal.isOpen', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  if (newValue)
                      console.log("This does not trigger...");
              }, true);

              $document.bind('keydown', function (e) {

                  if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
                      scope.modal.isOpen = true;
                      elem.find('input')[0].focus();

                  }
              ..........
              });
```

Comment: Try `$scope.apply()`

Comment: It works, but I'm trying to avoid using scope.apply. is there another way without using scope.apply?

Comment: if you want to update model you should use $apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep watch on property which shouldn't have `scope` in the string given to `$watch` function.

```
scope.$watch('modal.isOpen', function(newValue, oldValue) {
```

And the while modifying `scope` from custom event, wouldn't update binding. You need to kick digest cycle using `$timeout`/`$apply()` to update binding.(If any code ran ouside of angular context, angular doesn't run digest cycle to update bindings).

```
$document.bind('keydown', function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
    $timeout(function() {
      scope.modal.isOpen = true;
      elem.find('input')[0].focus();
    });
  }
  ..........
});
```

Comment: $timeout kicks off $apply?

Comment: @user1142130 yes..it kicks off digest cycle in safer way..I will never conflict with the digest cycle which is running already..

Comment: @sani Thanks mate..I think I've helped you many times..& learnt many things by helping.. :)